# SharePoint 2010: How to filter search results on a content type and a boolean column = true

Tags: 2010, search-results, filter

I am using SharePoint2010. I have a search result webpart with a filter on a content type. I would like to append this filter with a boolean column = true.

See below the current filter:

> (ContentType="Project portal")

I would like to append the filter with column SRExperienceRecord=True

Should it be something like this???

> (ContentType="Project portal") and SRExperienceRecord=True
>
> (ContentType="Project portal") and SRExperienceRecord=1

This is the managed property which I craeted. I did a full crawl already.

```
$managedProperty         = "SRExperienceRecord"
$managedPropertyType     = "3"
$refinementEnabled       = $true
$crawledProperty         = "ows_srExperienceRecord"
CreateManagedProperty -managedPropertyName $managedProperty -managedPropertyType $managedPropertyType -refinementEnabled $refinementEnabled
CreateCrawledPropertyMapping $managedProperty $crawledProperty
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
ContentType="Project portal" and SRExperienceRecord="True"
```

Comment: You can mark your own reply as answer to close this question.